# Error packaging a python application to make it pip-installable

Tags: python, django, git, github, pip

I am new to git, and deployed my first python-django app via github:
https://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils

The problem is that, when I try to install it, I get the error:

```
$ pip install -e git://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils.git#egg=django-crud-utils
Obtaining django-crud-utils from git+git://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils.git#egg=django-crud-utils
  Updating /home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/src/django-crud-utils clone
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-crud-utils
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/src/django-crud-utils/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        DESC = " ".join(__import__('crud_utils').__doc__.splitlines()).strip()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/src/django-crud-utils/setup.py", line 15, in <module>

    DESC = " ".join(__import__('crud_utils').__doc__.splitlines()).strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/src/django-crud-utils
Storing complete log in /home/static/.pip/pip.log
```

Any help?
Tks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a docstring on the `crud_utils` package, thus installation fails.

You can get the same error by just running the `setup.py` module locally:

```
python setup.py
```

Add a docstring to your [`crud_utils/__init__.py` module](https://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils/blob/master/crud_utils/__init__.py):

```
"""Some docstring here would help"""
```

<sub><sup>P.S. You also checked in the `.pyc` byte-compiled cache files into GitHub, you may want to remove those.</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I tried to delete all .pyc and .*~ files I added before, but it didn't commit. I don't know why...

Comment: You need to `git rm` the files to tell git that you want them removed.

Comment: I did a `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec git rm -f {} \;` and a `find . -name "*.*~" -exec git rm -f {} \;` Then I commited with -a. Everything clean now! Thanks.